# Export MySQL database to sql file with Python os.system

Tags: python, mysql, os.system

I want to export a database to sql file with Python, so I tried this

```
import os
os.system('mysqldump -u root -p database > database.sql')
```

and it asks me to write the password of the root user in the shell, but I'm doing a GUI application, so I don't want the user to interact with the shell.

Is it possible to give it the password in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prompt the user for the password and insert it into the command.

```
import os
os.system('mysqldump -u root -p%s database > database.sql' % password)
```

The syntax is `-pmypass` or `--password=mypass`

Comment: Just because it is so unusual I want to be explicit here: There is NO SPACE between `-p` and `yourpassword`!